# Update / Concatenation In SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Management Studio and I've added a new column where I want to concatenate (numerical) values from three other columns into the new column. I used Alter to add the new column and was now trying to use Update Set to finish it, but I can't figure it out. I was also trying to use concatenate functions but it wasn't working and I wasn't sure if Management Studio has a concatenate function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you post all the relevant code.

Comment: Concatenate is a string function! Is your new column a string? Give some examples is 1 & 10 & 1 1101 or 11001 for example.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/A9xXO6K.png

Sorry, I am new to this. I am trying to combine A, D, E (as a string, not as a sum) into "Challenge Two".

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a casting issue.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET NewColumn = CAST(OLDCOLUMN1 AS Varchar) + CAST(OLDCOLUMN2 AS VARCHAR) + CAST(OLDCOLUMN3 AS VARCHAR)
```

Have you tried casting your values that you are concatinating?

If so, provide us with some code you have ;)

Comment: You may want to add in a width for the VARCHARs in your CAST otherwise the text could be truncated.

Comment: Thanks, getting closer, But it doesn't seem to let me do this because it will delete columns from the data set, which I cannot do. Is there a way of creating this new column without getting rid of the old ones.

Here's the error message it's showing me http://i.imgur.com/MLb3faz.png?1?7440

Comment: Hey judda, just saw that; what kind of width are you talking about?

Comment: The error message simply means that your are trying to put 10 characters into a 5 character field or something like that.  Also, creating a field is a bad idea.  If you need that concatenation often enough, a function is a better way to go.

Comment: I've been struggling on what function to actually use though. I want to use Concat but that doesn't seem to work; it's giving me a weird error message saying concat function requires 2 to 254 arguments.